# Is there a way to specify which kernel is used to import files (SOLVED)?

Tags: import, parallelization, memory, kernel, json-format

Following up on a [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89857/possible-memory-leak-when-importing-json) in which I encountered a memory leak in the JSON importer I have created a SandBox script that will run the Import and analysis on a separate kernel, which be terminated when the analysis is complete.

The problem I have encountered is that the memory growth does not occur on the new kernel, but instead happens on one of the main (?) kernels opened when Mathematica is launched. So, my question is whether someone can explain why the SandBox method below does not contain the memory leak associated with importing JSON files... even better would be a suggestion for another work-around.

The code that I use is as follows:
EDIT: Code has been changed to include the crucial missing line.

```
SandBox[computation_, arguments___] := 
  Block[{result, kernel},
   kernel = LaunchKernels[1][[1]];
   DistributeDefinitions[computation,arguments];(*EDIT: Adding this line solves the issue - see comment from Szabolcs below*)
   result = ParallelEvaluate[computation[arguments], kernel];
   CloseKernels[kernel];
   Return[result];
   ];
CachedComputation[cachePath_String, computation_, arguments___] :=
  Block[{results,kernel},
   If[FileExistsQ[cachePath],
    Print["Loaded: ", cachePath];
    Return[Get[cachePath]];
    ];
   results = computation[arguments];
   Put[results, cachePath];
   Print["Created: ", cachePath];
   Return[results];
   ];
Table[CachedComputation[
  NotebookDirectory[] <> "test" <> ToString[t],
  SandBox[analysis, #] &,
  filepaths[[p]]
  ], {p, 1, Length[filepaths]}]
```

The analysis method imports a file specified by file paths[[p]]. The cached computation method ensures that when the memory leak from importing causes a crash I can resume analysis. The SandBox method was a suggestion from Nigel Hess of Wolfram for dealing with leaky code.

Comment: I haven't read carefully yet, but on a first glance the most likely cause might be that definitions (of `analysis`, etc.) are not distributed to the subkernel.  Look up `DistributeDefinitions`.  With most high level parallelization functions (`ParallelTable`, etc.), this is done automatically. A notable exception is `ParallelEvaluate`, which does not auto-distribute.  I guess that's because it's one of those functions meant to give lower-level control.

Comment: Szabolcs, you are absolutely right - `DistributeDefintions` was missing. Adding it above (and also declaring ParallelNeeds for custom packages) ensures that the Import operation runs on the sub-kernel... thereby bottling the memory leak in my previous question. THANK YOU!